# When I swipe the image the carousel left and right, that time the whole website is moving down(for ios mobile only)

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, carousel, owl-carousel

The Problem is when I swipe the carousel at that time the whole website is moving down.This issue only for IOS mobile(EX iPhone 5,6,7,8,10,11 etc).Please help me I can't figure out.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvXkh.png]

Website link:https://www.dubairent.com/property/-1-bed-high-floor-szr-view-vacant-spacious-470012

Please check-in iPhone

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. you can check through URL, that I already shared.Website link:https://www.dubairent.com/property/-1-bed-high-floor-szr-view-vacant-spacious-470012